How To Add Link With Thumbnails In Sidebar In WordPress
I'm trying to add few manual links with thumbnails in sidebar using Custom HTML Widget. The thumbnail images are unclickable as I do not know how to make them clickable. My main problem is that when I insert links with thumbnails, they do not appear in a symmetric way. Some images and texts move to right side and look very odd.
I'm using following code in WIDGET:
<p><img class="alignleft size-smallthumb wp-image-2500" src="https://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/quotes1-100x80.jpg" width="100" height="80" /><a href = "https://www.siteurl.com/quotes/inspirational-quotes/" target= "_blank">Inspirational Quote1</a></p>

There are 10 more URLS Like this.
NOTE: smallthumb is ID for THUMBNAIL Image
HERE IS THE CSS STYLE I AM USING:
img.alignleft {margin: 0 10px 0 5px;display: inline-block;}

You can see screenshot here:(https://i.sstatic.net/fzaWog16.png)
I tried very hard but could not get these links in a proper format. Thanks in advance...

The alignleft class applies float:left (from the WP/theme stylesheet), and that's why you get that effect. Try and add clear: left to your own rule you got there.

1.make images clickable: wrap the  tags with  tags to make them clickable.the  tag should have the href attribute set to the url you want to navigate to wen image is clicked
2.css for symmetry: to enshure that the images and texts align symmetrically,you can use flexbox or grid layout styles.you will also need to enshure that the images have a fixed size for consistency
<div class="box">
<a href="url here">
  <img src="img url" id="imagebox" class="box-inner" alt="mainpage">

css part:
.box{

  display: flex;

  align-items:center;

  margin-bottom:10px;

}

.box-inner{

  margin-right:10px;

  width:100px;

  height:auto;

  display:block;

}


@CBroe, thank you very much... you solved my problem with just one style. clear: left really worked and all thumbnails appear in a row. Just a little problem here:  except top thumbnail all 9 thumbs do not have a gap between them. i.e. they touch one another. I tried to add margin-bottom: 10 px but it overlaps another widget below and deteriorates it. Anyway thanks for your quick help and guidance.

@ppsren add padding-bottom
